# Lilypond - Modern Gregorian Drop Cap Letter

Tags: lilypond

How can I replace a section of the instrument name with a big drop cap letter colored red?

[image: ![Drop cap]

```
\score {
  \relative {
  c' c c c
  c c c c
  }
  \addlyrics {
  longtext longtext longtext longtext
  longtext longtext longtext longtext
  }
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Lyrics
      \override LyricSpace.minimum-distance = #1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The font design is not perfect this way (you’d want to use different types for the the different font-sizes, i.e. `\override #'(font-name . "...")`), but this should help you to get there:

```
\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = 
  \markup \with-color #red
  \override #'(baseline-skip . 0)
  \center-column {
    Ant.
    \vspace #0.3
    \fontsize #-2 VII
    \vspace #0.5
    \fontsize #9 A
  }
  \override InstrumentName.self-alignment-Y = #0.45
} { g'8[ a'] c''[ b' a'] b'[ c''] }
```